# TargetException was unhandled

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, properties, casting

I'm trying to allow someone to run a query on a single table by passing in a Dictionary of column names and values. It was originally breaking on when I was restricting returnVersions so I put in the currentvalue to test it. I'm still getting the same error even when trying to cast the get to a string. I'm not sure why it is doing this. Below you will find the code, the exception and the stack trace.

Code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs a query on the version table based on a Dictionary you pass in
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queries">Dictonary... key = column name, value = value in column</param>
    /// <returns>List of MVersions matching all params, null if none</returns>
    public static List<MVersion> QueryVersions(Dictionary<string, object> queries)
    {
        if (queries.Count > 0)
        {
            IREntities context = new IREntities();

            var listOfProperties = typeof(version).GetProperties().ToList();

            List<MVersion> returnVersions = GetAllVersions();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> currentQuery in queries)
            {
                List<string> currentlistofstring = listOfProperties.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToList();
                var currentProperty = listOfProperties.Where(p => p.ToString().Split(' ').ElementAtOrDefault(1) == currentQuery.Key).FirstOrDefault();
                string currrentvalue = currentProperty.GetValue(returnVersions.ElementAtOrDefault(0), null).ToString();
                returnVersions = returnVersions.Where(v => currentProperty.GetValue(v).ToString() == currentQuery.Value.ToString()).ToList();
            }

            return returnVersions;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Exception (no inner exception):

```
{"Object does not match target type."}
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at IR.Model.Models.MVersion.QueryVersions(Dictionary`2 queries) in c:\Users\recursor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CS3280\Final Project\IR\IR.Model\Models\MVersion.cs:line 170
   at IR.Controller.CVersion.QueryVersions(Dictionary`2 queries) in c:\Users\recursor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CS3280\Final Project\IR\IR.Controller\CVersion.cs:line 125
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\recursor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CS3280\Final Project\IR\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 40
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The current error is occurring on the string currentvalue line.

**EDIT 1:**
The error is in the same spot. I changed the invocation of split to actually have the char ' ' in it. I'm still getting the same error, but from the stack trace as well as the debugger it looks like it is able to get to the GetValue method (currentProperty gets the actual System.string idversion property it seems), but then it fumbles the object when it comes out. Any ideas on what I should check next?

Answer (score 0):

The typeof was an entity when it needed to be the model. aka `typeof(MVersion)`